# filter file content to sorted tables

Tags: shell, unix, awk, zsh, file-format

I have a file that contains  the following lines of code. here the file displays a schedules which are sorted one by one .

```html
at 12:00 the schedule of james version1 is :
first_task:eating:nothing
second_task:rest:onehour
third_task:watching:nothing 

at 12:00 the schedule of james version2 is :
first_task:eating:fruits
second_task:rest:twohour
third_task:watching:manga 

at 12:00 the schedule of alex version1 is :
first_task:eating:fruit
second_task:rest:halfhour
third_task:watching:horrorfilm 

at 12:00 the schedule of alex version2 is :
first_task:eating:meal
second_task:rest:nothing
third_task:watching:nothing 

at 18:00 the schedule of james version1 is :
first_task:eating:fastfood
second_task:rest:twohours
third_task:watching:series 

at 18:00 the schedule of james version2 is :
first_task:eating:nothing
second_task:rest:onehours
third_task:watching:series 

at 18:00 the schedule of alex version1 is :
first_task:eating:vegetals
second_task:rest:threehours
third_task:watching:manga 

at 18:00 the schedule of alex version2 is :
first_task:eating:bread
second_task:rest:fivehours
third_task:watching:manga 

at 22:00 the schedule of james version1 is :
first_task:eating:nothing
second_task:rest:sevenhours
third_task:watching:nothing

at 22:00 the schedule of james version2 is :
first_task:eating:meal
second_task:rest:sixnhours
third_task:watching:nothing

at 22:00 the schedule of alex version1 is :
first_task:eating:vegetals
second_task:rest:sevehours
third_task:watching:manga 

at 22:00 the schedule of alex version2 is :
first_task:eating:icecream
second_task:rest:sevenhours
third_task:watching:nothing
```

I've tried to sort it this way :

```html
12:00 eating:fruit
18:00 eating:vegetals
22:00 eating:nothing

12:00 rest:onhour 
18:00 rest:threehour
22:00 rest:sevenhour

12:00 watching:horrorfilm 
18:00 watching:manga
22:00 watching:nothing
```

using these commands :

```html
awk -F '[\ :]' '/the schedule is/{h=$2;m=$3} /eating/{print " "h":"m" watching:"$3}' f.txt
awk -F '[\ :]' '/the schedule is/{h=$2;m=$3} /rest/{print " "h":"m" rest:"$3}' f.txt
awk -F '[\ :]' '/the schedule is/{h=$2;m=$3} /watching/{print " "h":"m" watching:"$3}' f.txt
```

Now I am looking to improve the filtered file by ignoring all non significant words and sorting the most valuable information in a table , I've tried to think/search how get this format but in vain .

Comment: No, there isn't, you or someone else would need to write one. Please edit your question to show what you've tried. Is that REALLY the output format you want though? It's not really CSV and it'd be incredibly hard to do anything with afterwards given the various line formats and blank lines. Why do some of the blocks from the input not appear in the output? If there's some logic behind deleting them, then edit your question to tell us what it is. If every block from the input is instead supposed to be in the output then edit your question to show that.

Comment: @Ed Morton I have edited the post question

Comment: How you want your table to look like?