# filter a file in table

Tags: awk, sed, zsh, filefilter

this question is a follow  up of a previous question entitled [filter file content to sorted tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31056587/filter-file-content-to-sorted-tables),I didn't get a satisfactory answers so I have added more explanation on how the results should looks like .

I have a file that contains the following lines of code. here the file displays a schedules which are sorted one by one .

```html
at 12:00 the schedule of james version1 is :
first_task:eating:nothing
second_task:rest:onehour
third_task:watching:nothing 

at 12:00 the schedule of james version2 is :
first_task:eating:fruits
second_task:rest:twohour
third_task:watching:manga 

at 12:00 the schedule of alex version1 is :
first_task:eating:fruit
second_task:rest:halfhour
third_task:watching:horrorfilm 

at 12:00 the schedule of alex version2 is :
first_task:eating:meal
second_task:rest:nothing
third_task:watching:nothing 

at 18:00 the schedule of james version1 is :
first_task:eating:fastfood
second_task:rest:twohours
third_task:watching:series 

at 18:00 the schedule of james version2 is :
first_task:eating:nothing
second_task:rest:onehours
third_task:watching:series 

at 18:00 the schedule of alex version1 is :
first_task:eating:vegetals
second_task:rest:threehours
third_task:watching:manga 

at 18:00 the schedule of alex version2 is :
first_task:eating:bread
second_task:rest:fivehours
third_task:watching:manga 

at 22:00 the schedule of james version1 is :
first_task:eating:nothing
second_task:rest:sevenhours
third_task:watching:nothing

at 22:00 the schedule of james version2 is :
first_task:eating:meal
second_task:rest:sixnhours
third_task:watching:nothing

at 22:00 the schedule of alex version1 is :
first_task:eating:vegetals
second_task:rest:sevehours
third_task:watching:manga 

at 22:00 the schedule of alex version2 is :
first_task:eating:icecream
second_task:rest:sevenhours
third_task:watching:nothing
```

I've tried to sort it this way :

```html
12:00 eating:fruit
18:00 eating:vegetals
22:00 eating:nothing

12:00 rest:onhour 
18:00 rest:threehour
22:00 rest:sevenhour

12:00 watching:horrorfilm 
18:00 watching:manga
22:00 watching:nothing
```

using these commands :

```html
awk -F '[\ :]' '/the schedule is/{h=$2;m=$3} /eating/{print " "h":"m" watching:"$3}' f.txt
awk -F '[\ :]' '/the schedule is/{h=$2;m=$3} /rest/{print " "h":"m" rest:"$3}' f.txt
awk -F '[\ :]' '/the schedule is/{h=$2;m=$3} /watching/{print " "h":"m" watching:"$3}' f.txt
```

Now I am looking to improve the filtered file by ignoring all non significant words and sorting the most valuable information in a table , I've tried to think/search how get this format but in vain .

```html
James version1,12:00,18:00,22:00
eating,nothing,fastfood,nothing
rest,onehour,halfhour,sevenhours
watching,nothing,series,nothing

James version2,12:00,18:00,22:00
eating,fruits,nothing,meal
rest,twohour,onehours,sixnhours
watching,manga,series,nothing 

alex version1,12:00,18:00,22:00
eating,fruit,vegetals,vegetals
rest,halfhour,threehours,sevehours
watching,horrorfilm,manga,manga 

alex version2,12:00,18:00,22:00
eating,meal,bread,icecream
rest,nothing,fivehours,sevenhours
watching,nothing,manga,nothing
```

Comment: @Rakholiya Jenish cuz I didn't get any response

Comment: @Rakholiya Jenish I wonder if you can delete it ?

Comment: Just stick to one of the questions.

Comment: @fedorqui I have added the reason why I've duplicated the question .

Comment: If you don't get an answer to a question, you have to edit it, provide more details, etc. Asking another one with more details is no-sense, because you are asking the same question. If you feel more attached to this one, you can remove the other one and this would be reopened.

Comment: Some hints for you.  Define what your record is and what your fields are.  For example try this `BEGIN{RS = "" ; FS = "\n" } END{print NR}` will separate the text into records and print the number of records.